# How to make omitting search criteria

Tags: windows, windows-8, file-search

How to ask windows to search for files that not satisfy defined condition. For example I don't need files that has extension `log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and write in the search `name -log`

Lets say you have a file appendix.tex and appendix.log to exclude the .log file you should write in the search `appendix -log` (you can write more than one thing you want to exclude like -log -pdf -png ...)